# Python 2.7 having multiple say commands on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have tried many things to try to get text to speech to work in python 2.7 on a mac. I managed to write some simple codes using the system os such as:

```
from os import system
system('say Hello world')
```

This works alone:

```
from os import system
string2 = 'test'
string1 = 'hello world' + string2 + '.'
system("say %s" %(string1))
```

But if I do multiple say commands, like this:

```
system('say Please tell me your name.')
name = raw_input()
st = "Hello. Want pie" + name + "?"
system("say " + st)
```

I get this error after I enter my name:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Am I currently making a mistake in concept, or does having two say commands not work? If having two say commands do not work this way, then how can I use text to speech multiple times in python 2.7 with macintosh?

Comment: It seems you did not use the name, why input it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I accidentally copied a previous version of my program. It currently looks like this.

Comment: Your code works on my Mac. I suggest that you paste the code exactly; we can't debug if we can't reproduce the bug. The error message seems to indicate there was an extra single quote in your code. Please also specify what your input is; if it is something like "O'Brien", that would be why. In any case, I can't imagine it being because of two say commands in a row as such.

Comment: I used the code directly. This may not help, but I use Wing 101 to run python applications.

Comment: The name input is Bob

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing the format and see if you have any better luck.

```
system('say Please tell me your name.')
name = raw_input()
st = "Hello. Want pie" + name + "?"
system('say %s' %(st))
```